# JavaFx GridPane layout how to set margin for an element in row?

Tags: javafx, margin, gridpane

I'm using GridPane layout for positioning things in my application. I'm wondering how I can set margin for an element in row

```
         GridPane.setConstraints(chip5, 1, 1, 1, 1, HPos.RIGHT, VPos.TOP); //I want to set 
       //  margin for chip5 from top (for example 5px)
```

Is it possible in GridPane?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the margin for any particular `Node`:

```
GridPane.setMargin(chip5, new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 5):

In FXML, you can do it as follows:

```
<TextField fx:id="txtFirstName" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
    <GridPane.margin>
        <Insets right="30"/>
    </GridPane.margin>
</TextField>
```