# JavaFX gridPane padding for specific cell

Tags: javafx, margin, padding, gridpane

I'm making a custom gridPane as a form and have the alignment for the left column on the right and the alignment for the right column of the left.

The last row is always the buttons (save/cancel), but I would like the padding for those to be higher so they're more spread out.

Is it possible (probably) to set the padding/margin for the specific cell (fe the right button)?

Comment: [Gluon Scenebuilder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) makes this type of stuff a lot easier.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson, I do use Scenebuilder for most of the GUI, but the form has different controls for different Objects.
That's why I did this one in code to easly swap out the controls I don't need.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think setting that row's [`RowConstraints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) will help.

Comment: I'm using RowConstrains for the height of the rows.
I found what I was looking for here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634470/javafx-gridpane-layout-how-to-set-margin-for-an-element-in-row